# Can you geotarget a tab on a Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook

I have a client that needs to have an application installed on a Facebook page tab but have the tab only appear to certain markets. I know how this can be done when posting comments on the pages wall but can this be done for the tabs?

Thanks in advance!

Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add restrictions to your application which will prevent the tab for that application from being visible to people who don't meet the restrictions (certain country or certain age).  This has a side effect that people who aren't logged into facebook also can't see the tab until they log in.

Facebook recently posted examples on setting application restrictions with the graph api - https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/574

I have a blog post from earlier this year that talks about this a little bit - http://dev.beaffinitive.com/facebook-iframe-tabs-for-pages-and-app-restri

Also, I posted sample php application to github - https://github.com/Affinitive/FacebookRestrictedTab

Answer (score 0):

We've talked to a Facebook rep about this, their response was that you have to handle the geo-targeting of the tab through a 3rd party developer or do it yourself.  Facebook does not support geo-targeting the tabs natively at this time.  Starbucks and Coca-Cola were listed as examples of companies using geo-targeting in their tabs.

No idea when http://ekstreme.com/geotargeting was published, but it seems like a good guide to setting up very basic geo-targeting based on IP if you want to do it yourself.